# InvalidOperationException when using Keyboard.Modifiers in a Task

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, task

I'm using the following code in my WPF Project :

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        () =>
                        {
                            if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt) // <- Here
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);                            
                        })
                        .ContinueWith(t =>
                        {
                          // do somthing
                        });
```

and i'll get the InvalidOperationException on :

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt)
```

and it tells me :

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require
>   this.

I just don't get it !! It seems to be a simple code, but why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go onto the UI thread to get access to the Keyboard. Try this:

```
                Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        () =>
                        {
                            if ((bool)Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Func<bool>(() =>
                            {
                                 return Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt;
                             })))
                             {
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);                            
                             }
                        })
                        .ContinueWith(t =>
                        {
                          // do somthing
                        });
```

Comment: Thank, Exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It's cross-thread access to control property. You should use `Dispatcher` in this case.
See [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)